# Google Tag Manger: can you create a custom trigger that fires when a cookie has been created?

Tags: google-tag-manager

While we were updating our website we ran into some tags that ended up breaking. A quick fix to could be just setting a cookie in the browser and updating our tag to fire when the cookie exists. Is there a custom tag configuration in google tag manager that could allow me to do this or do I need to figure out a different work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as such. For a trigger to be fired you need an event, that is, a dataLayer push that adds an object that contains the key "event" to the dataLayer array.

There are built-in events (such as page load, dom ready, page loaded, and click and submit when you enable the respective variables) and custom events, i.e. arbitrary values for the event key.

Only when an event is present GTM can read the cookie and update its internal variables with the cookie values.

For practical purposes, I think you can use a custom event trigger, tick the "use regex" checkbox and enter ".*" (the regex for "whatever"). Then, after you have created a first party cookie variable that reads your "update ready cookie", you specify a firing condition for that trigger with "update ready cookie does not equal undefined".

Than you basically have "whatever happens next after the cookie is set" trigger which then can fire your tags.

On the other hand, since you presumably use JavaScript to set your cookie, you could just as well dispense with the cookie altogether and push a custom event to the dataLayer that triggers the tags.